# Motivic fundamental group of the moduli space of curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces, motives

Suppose I have a smooth projective family of varieties of varieties over $\mathcal M_g$ - i.e. a universal functor, commuting with deformations, from curves to smooth projective varieties. Can I compute its cohomology directly from the cohomology of the curves?

In some cases, like the functor associating a curve $C$ to the smooth projective variety $\operatorname{Sym}^n C$, I certainly can. Can I in general?

I think the right way to formalize this is to consider your favorite substitute for the conjectural category of relative motives - e.g. either $\ell$-adic sheaves or variations of Hodge structures. Consider the Tannakian category of relative motives on the stack $\mathcal M_g$ and take its Tannakian fundamental group $\pi_1^{mot} (\mathcal M_g)$. Then consider the interesting part, which I'm going to take to be the maximal reductive quotient of the identity component of $\pi_1^{mot} (\mathcal M_g)$. One should also take the kernel of the natural map tot he motivic Galois group of the base field.

Is this equal to $SP_{2g}$, the part coming from the universal family of curves, or is it larger?

---

One way to answer this would be to exhibit a smooth projective family over $\mathcal M_g$ with weird cohomology.

For $\mathcal A_g$, $g \geq 2$, I think you can show that the identity component of the motivic fundamental group (defined in an $\ell$-adic way) is exactly $SP_{2g}$ using the congruence subgroup property.

I'm also interested in the case where we restrict to motives with good reduction at every place.

Comment: Nice question!  In a weak sense, the answer is "yes" by Torelli, since the (polarized) cohomology knows the curve, hence whatever you construct from it.  I don't see how to get at the formalization you ask about (which I would say is more like "can we compute the cohomology of the new variety from the cohomology of the curve, via linear algebra operations?").

Comment: Actually, I think that the reductive part of $\pi_1^{mot}(M_g)$ would bigger than $Sp_{2g}$. You can see my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186133/which-mapping-class-group-representations-come-from-algebraic-geometry for why I think so.

Comment: @DanielLitt Good point. I guess I tend to think of the cohomology as a Galois representation rather than a Hodge structure.

Comment: @DonuArapura Yes, I agree. There should be no problem showing that these Prym-type families have big monodromy either by topology or moment methods. This is an example of what I asked for, but it still doesn't feel "exotic" to me, so probably I should have included this in the "expected" part. For the space of semistable vector bundles, is it the case that the irreducible factors come from SP_{2g} but the extension classes don't?

Comment: Will, no I would agree that these examples aren't exotic. The pure graded part of the moduli of semistable  bundles come from $Sp_{2g}$ as you surmised.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the moment method, but it sounds pretty difficult to apply. Doesn't it require you to know about the cohomology of all curves? Does it amount to: if most curves have the maximal MT group, then the monodromy is the MT group? But don't other results say that you just need a single curve with the maximal MT group?

Comment: @BenWieland To show a monodromy group is large, I can work with a particular family of curves and show that has large monodromy. To show the monodromy of a representation is large, I just need to show that the invariants of tensor powers of this representation are small. This is controlled by expected value of powers of the trace of Frobenius acting on the representation of a random point on that family of curves over a finite field. This type of thing can often be controlled with standard methods from probability theory.